# Python optimize fmin gives A value in x_new is above the interpolation range error

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, interpolation

I am trying to interpolate the minimum of a quadratic function of which I have three samples. The first test in the code snippet below works. It gives:
[image: test 1]

In the second test there are two similar values. The minimum of my quadratic function should lie in between. However, I get the following error

```
"A value in x_new is above the interpolation range."
```

Does anybody know a way how to solve this.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import optimize

def test(x, y):
    xmin, ymin = getMin(x, y)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x, y, 'o-r', xmin, ymin, 'bx')

def getMin(x, y):
    f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind="quadratic")
    xmin = optimize.fmin(lambda x: f(x), x[1])
    ymin = f(xmin)
    return xmin[0], ymin[0]

test([18, 19, 20], [-34.3, -74.3, -7.3])
test([18, 19, 20], [-34.3, -74.3, -74.2])
```

Comment: well you could increase your interpolation range. I am not sure how the interpolation is done, but it seems to need always 15 iterations. If your points are very close to each other it seems to be likely that in one iteration you are outside the interpolation range. 
Another possibility is (if you will stick to 3 data points) to solve some linear equations to find the minimum analytically

Comment: good idea to do it analytically. I will give it a shot. Did not realize that the optimizer stops if goes out of bounds before convergence during the optimization

Comment: Using f = interpolate.interp1d(x, y, kind="quadratic", bounds_error=False) works. Feel free to post it as an answer. I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Analytically works like a charm

```
def getMinFit(x, y):
    p = np.polyfit(x, y, 2)
    xmin = -p[1]/(2*p[0])
    ymin = np.polyval(p, xmin)
    return xmin, ymin
```

[image]

Comment: Glad that I could help